# Translation view path broken after upgrade to 8.5.1

Tags: views, path-aliases

After upgrading my site from Drupal 8.3.5 to Drupal 8.5.1, the token `{{ path }}` is not translated anymore in the selected language.

Does anyone have a suggestion or solution?

Comment: `Does anyone have a suggestion` [report it](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=1&version=8.5.1&component=All) as a bug

Answer (score 1):

Because Content: Path has been removed in 8.5 version. Instead you should use Link to Content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should use, but it won't give you the translated output and your link is stucked at the original language.

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2018-04-08/doesnt-show-path-field-when-adding-fields-for-view